# Cross Origin requests at server side

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

Hi I am facing issue in cross origin requests at server side when trying to open file which is retrieved from database using java.I am unaware of this cross orgin requests.When file is clicked then it is giving error as

jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/JR00432239/Desktop/trial/src/temp/filetest1.docx. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Here is my java code:

```
package fileretrieve;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.IOUtils;

import dbConnection.Dbconn;

@MultipartConfig
public class FileRetrieve extends HttpServlet {



    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          response.setContentType("text/plain");

          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();        
          String onelevel=request.getParameter("onelevel"); 







          Connection conn = null; // connection to the database
          String message = null;
          Statement st = null;// message will be sent back to client



          try {
              // connects to the database
              conn = Dbconn.getConnection();
                st = conn.createStatement();

                 PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("select data from files1 where board=?");
                 ps.setString(1,onelevel);                   
                 //out.print("<table width=25% border=1>");
                // out.print("<center><h1>Result:</h1></center>");
                 ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();                
                 /* Printing column names */
                 ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();
                 int count=0;
                 while(rs.next())
                    {
                     count=count+1;
                     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\JR00432239\\Desktop\\trial\\src\\temp\\filetest"+count+".docx");
                     fos.write(rs.getBytes(1));
                     fos.close();

//                 out.print("<tr>");
//                 out.print("<td>"+rsmd.getColumnName(1)+"</td>");
//                    out.print("<td><a href=\"file:///C:/Users/JR00432239/Desktop/trial/src/temp/test.pdf\" target=\"_self\">"+count+"</a></td></tr>");
//                    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home.html").forward(request, response);
                     System.out.println("writing...");
                     response.getWriter().write("{\"name\":\""+count+"\",\"path\":\"C:/Users/JR00432239/Desktop/trial/src/temp/filetest"+count+".docx\"}");



                 }


//                 out.print("</table>");
//                 


          }catch (Exception e2)
            {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }

          finally{

//            request.setAttribute("data", data);
//            RequestDispatcher rd =request.getRequestDispatcher("userview.jsp");
//            

              out.close();
            }


          // forwards to the message page
        //  getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home.html").forward(request, response);
   }

}
```

Here is my html code:
Submit

Here is my javascript page:

```
$("#retrieve").click(function(){

     $.ajax({
            url : 'FileRetrieve',
            method:"POST",
            data : {
                onelevel : $('#onelevel').val()
            },

            crossDomain: true,
            success : function(responseText) {
                var data=JSON.parse(responseText)
                $("#files_data").html('')
                $("#files_data").html('<table><tr><td><button onclick="getFile()">'+data.name+'</button></td></tr></table>')

            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            }
        });
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https` - so which protocol scheme are you using? note: `url : 'FileRetrieve',` isn't cross origin, ever, except in chrome on file:/// protocol scheme - but you can't be using file:/// because you have server side code, so ... confused much?

Comment: Actually I am storing all retieved files  in local folder. So I am using file:///

Comment: well, you can't, definitely not with Chrome

Answer (score 0):

If you're using chrome, as a simple solution try a chrome extention like **Allow-Control-Allow-Origin:***
 https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

if not fixed, 
run chrome using command line with the flag

```
path/to/chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

or just switch to firefox and check whether the issue is still there

this would be a quick-fix only in the development

**EDIT**

As far as I know, best thing you can do is make the files available in http server and access them using http protocol.

Comment: Ya I checked with chrome even there I am facing this issue

Comment: I checked in chrome with the above mentioned path but it didnt fix and also the same is repeating in chrome even

Comment: try making the files available in a http server and use http path when accessing files.

Comment: To make apache accessible files outside the application I tried to add   <context docBase="myfilepath" path="/static"/> to <host> tag in apache server.xml but I am facing same issue